The edit UI for SG posts with short body lines is thin
The main (left) column of some SG items' edit UIs are unnaturally thin. Ex.

Notice that the longest line in its body is not that many characters long- none of the lines wrap. Adding arbitrary characters to make any line in the post body longer causes the width of the main column to increase until the normal amount (and then the text wraps).

Alternatively, clicking "show tips" under the comment box makes it go to normal size.

Normal-ify it please?

Can't reproduce on my side (The edit column is thin initially while loading for a fraction of a second but then expands when everything is loaded up), my laptops screen size is a bit small though so will check later on a bigger screen.
